# Script para convertir .P12 a .CER

Tags: php, javascript, html, certificado-ssl

Hola estimada comunidad,

quisiera saber una forma de poder convertir de .p12 a .cer desde mi web he estado pensando que puede ser posible mediante un script

la logica es la siguiente

se sube el documento .p12

boton de expulsar  documento con extension.CER

espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Usa OpenSSL. http://php.net/manual/es/ref.openssl.php

Comment: Tal y como te ha recomendado @shop350 , puedes hacer uso de openssl en PHP de manera nativa sin llamar a comandos externos. En mi respuesta te he detallado cómo hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Alguna de las respuestas solucionaron tu problema? Haznos saber cualquier duda que tengas.

Answer (score 1):

Este comando te hace lo que buscas, deberías ejecutarlo en un script que sea llamado desde tu web con el fichero que el usuario introduzca:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.p12 -out certificate.cer -nodes
```

¿Intentas hacer algo así? https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html

Si lees la diferencia entre .p12 y .cer, verás que lo que intentas hacer no debería hacerse (suponiendo que se pudiese)

https://www.sede.fnmt.gob.es/preguntas-frecuentes/problemas-y-dudas/-/asset_publisher/fVZppcBHj0oa/content/1553-diferencias-entre-pfx-p12-cer-y-crt-

Comment: Si efectivamente quiero hacer algo como esto https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html,  en nuestra web: http://certificados-digitales.pe/

Comment: ¿Pero te has dado cuenta que un p12 contiene la clave **privada** de un certificado y quieres convertirlo a .cer que tiene la clave **pública**? ¿Por qué yo iba a darte mi clave privada a tí para que me lo conviertas si puedo utilizar un comando y evito problemas de seguridad dándote datos confidenciales? Supongo que tendréis vuestros motivos

Comment: Somos entidad certificadora queremos facilitarle a nuestros clientes cambiar la extension  a .cer para que puedan usar en su sistema de facturacion electronica que utiliza el ente regulador de impuestos, no almacenaremos dato alguno de las claves del cliente solo queremos hacer una herramienta que cambio la extension.

Comment: Bueno,tampoco es sitio para hablar de esas cosas aquí :) ¿Te sirvió mi solución?

Comment: No mucho pero gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no te funcionó, el comando no sirve?

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar el trabajo que deseas con funciones nativas de PHP necesitas hacer uso de:

- [`openssl_pkcs12_read()`](http://php.net/openssl_pkcs12_read): Convierte un Almacén de Certificado PKCS#12 a una matriz.
- [`openssl_pkey_export()`](http://php.net/openssl_pkey_export): Obtiene una representación de una clave exportable a una cadena.

Con `openssl_pkcs12_read()` obtendremos una matriz con los índices `cert` y `pkey`. El que nos interesa usar en el siguiente paso es `pkey`.

Con `openssl_pkey_export()` convertimos un certificado de entrada (en este caso, en forma de cadena codificada en PEM) en un certificado de salida codificado en PEM en el parámetro pasado por referencia.

Ambas funciones devuelven `true` en caso de haber ido bien el proceso (las claves de entrada y sus contraseñas son válidas) o bien `false` si ocurrió un error.

Un ejemplo de uso podría ser:

```
<?php
/* Definimos dónde está alojado el archivo .p12 */
$archivo = $_FILES[...];
$clave = '(contraseña, si la tiene)';
$resultado = [];
$ok = openssl_pkcs12_read(file_get_contents($archivo), $resultado, $clave);
if($ok === false) {
    die(openssl_error_string());
}
/* 'pkey' es la clave privada obtenida en la función anterior */
$ok = openssl_pkey_export($resultado['pkey'], $resultado, $clave);
if($ok === false) {
    die(openssl_error_string());
}
/* El contenido del certificado .cer está en $resultado */
```

---

Prueba de concepto con un archivo p12 codificado en base64 para facilitar su uso aquí:

```
<?php
$clave = 'clave';
$resultado = [];
$ok = openssl_pkcs12_read(
  base64_decode('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'),
  $resultado, $clave);
if($ok === false) {
    die(openssl_error_string());
}
/* 'pkey' es la clave privada obtenida en la función anterior */
$ok = openssl_pkey_export($resultado['pkey'], $resultado, $clave);
if($ok === false) {
    die(openssl_error_string());
}
/* El contenido del certificado .cer codificado en PEM está en $resultado */
echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars($resultado), '</pre>', PHP_EOL;
```

El resultado mostrado en el navegador será:

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```